# Remotely executed batch file calling an external executable

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-server-2012-r2

I am trying to call a .cmd file on a remote server (which works) and from that .cmd file call an external executable on the remote server to compress some files.  This used to work in an older environment (remote server was a 2003 machine), but we are migrating to a new 2012r2 server and now I am getting a path not found error.  I know the path's are correct, because locally I can run all of these commands without any problems.  Let me lay it out a bit cleaner:

Calling server:
I use the following command line to call the script which lives on the remote server:

```
\\server1\path1a\path1b\myscript.cmd \\server1\path2a\path2b\
```

Remote server:
On here the contents of the "myscript.cmd" file is:

```
@echo off
e:\utils\gzip.exe -N -3 -a %1\p*
if %errorlevel% GTR 0 goto zipfail
echo ZIP WORKED!
exit

:zipfail
echo ZIP FAILED with error: %errorlevel%
exit
```

As you can see I am passing in a parameter to where the source files to be zipped live.  The account on the calling server that I using has Full Access (both file and share level) to the directory where the .cmd file lives, as well as to the local path e:\utils where on the remote server the gzip utility lives.  I can run this from the remote server and it all works normally, but when I try to call it from a remote machine I get back and error of "the system cannot fine the path specified".  I've confirmed that the issue is not the "c:\utils\gzip.exe" path, in that if that is missing or incorrect I get a different error which states that it cannot find the gzip utility.  That means the issue is getting gzip to launch and have it access the remote path where the files are to be compressed.

(BTW, I have tried putting gzip to the same path where the .cmd file lives, same results.)

Any ideas?  Is this some new security restriction on 2012 whereby a remote executing script is unable/not allowed to access remote executables?

Comment: Please post the full command line you use to start the command remotely

Comment: Please remove `@echo off` and see if that provides any clues. Running `\\server1\path1a\path1b\myscript.cmd` copies the .cmd script from the remote machine to your machine and runs it. This does not run anything on the remote machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paul was right - its been too long since I have worked with batch files that I am starting to forget the basics... grrrr!

The path (and called executable) was missing on the calling (aka machine running the script).  Once I fixed that its was working great!